# rmdir() bug with particular filename? Permission denied

Tags: php, directory, permission-denied, rmdir

First, let's get these out of the way:

- There are no open handles on the directory.
- There are no files in the directory.
- `chmod` ing the permissions to 0777 does not prevent the error.
- the directory name is correct.

Now then, here's my problem.  `rmdir()` is throwing this error when trying to delete the directory:

> rmdir(098f6bcd4621d373cade4e832627b4f6) [function.rmdir]: Permission denied in path\to\administrate.php on line 124

**098f6bcd4621d373cade4e832627b4f6** is the name of the directory.

Here is the relevant portion of the script.

```
if(is_dir($userhash)) :
foreach (new DirectoryIterator($userhash) as $fileInfo) {
    $fileName = $fileInfo->getFilename();
    if($fileInfo->isDot()) continue;

    if(!rename($userhash.'/'.$fileName , 'trashcan/'.$username.'/'.$fileName)) {
        echo '<p class="error">Could not move '.$fileName.'</p>';
        $err = 1;
    }
}
else :
    echo '<p class="error">Unable to delete files! error: 67</p>';
    $err = 1;
endif;

    //JUST TO BE SURE
    chmod('./',0777);
    chmod($userhash,0777);

// RMDIR ONCE THE DIR IS EMPTY.
if(rmdir($userhash))
    echo '<p class="success">Deleted the user directory. The files are in the trash.</p>';
else {
    echo '<p class="error">Could not remove the user directory. Error: 656</p>';
    $err = 1;
}
```

### Update

I manually created the dir `'jake'` in the same directory.  I did `rmdir('jake');` and it worked great.  Now, I manually created a dir `'098f6bcd4621d373cade4e832627b4f6'` in the same directory. I did `rmdir('098f6bcd4621d373cade4e832627b4f6');` and it errored!

### Update 2

This is beginning to look like some weird `rmdir()` bug, as unlikely as that seems. Here are directory names I've created and then tried to remove with `rmdir`;

```
098f6bcd4621d373cade4e832627b4f6        |  didn't work (quintuple checked)
098f6bcd4621d373cade4e832627b4f7        |  worked
098f6bcd4621d373cade4e832627b4f         |  worked
098f6bcd4621d373cade4e832627b4f66       |  worked
```

Comment: Well, @Navi, This is on my windows pc, Xampp install.  When looking at the directory info, it says "0 folders, 0 files". I have "view hidden files" on as well.  There's nothing in there.

Comment: It may (or not) be worth noting that the string in question is the md5 hash of 'test'

Answer (score 2):

In order to be able remove file:

- user should have write permissions to PARENT directory
- restricted deletion flag should NOT be set for PARENT directory

**UPDATE:**
About restricted deletion flag - from `man chmod`:

> RESTRICTED DELETION FLAG OR STICKY BIT
>
> The restricted deletion flag or sticky
>   bit is a single bit, whose
>   interpretation depends on the file
>   type.  For directories, it prevents 
>   unprivi‐leged  users  from  removing
>   or renaming a file in the directory
>   unless they own the file or the
>   directory; this is called the
>   restricted deletion flag for the
>   directory, and is commonly found on
>   world-writable directories like /tmp. 
>   For regular files on some older
>   systems, the bit saves the program's
>   text image on the swap device so it
>   will load more quickly when run; this
>   is called the sticky bit.

You may SET it by adding 1 to the first octal digit in mode, for example:

```
chmod 1xxx dirname
```

**UPDATE 2:**

Does user, under which php is executed, has permissions to chmod parent directory?

In other words, are you sure that first chmod call returns true?

```
chmod('./',0777);
```

Comment: Tell me more about the "restricted deletion flag" ...?

Comment: Thank you for the extra information, but since I've `chmod`ed the directory to 0777, the sticky bit is NOT set, right? So I don't think that's the issue.

Comment: Did you do that for PARENT directory?

Comment: The problem directory is in the same directory as the php script. I did: `chmod('./',0777);`  Did I do it right @Kel ?  I'll add it in to the code above just so you can see it in context.

Comment: If ./ is a parent directory of directory you are trying to remove - than yes.

Comment: 1) Does user, under which php is executed, has permissions to chmod parent directory? (in other words, are you sure that first chmod returns True?). 2) If this does not help, the only thing I can suppose is that there are opened handlers to file inside directory. BTW, this should not cause such error... You may check code part-by-part to localize error.